# Kafka rest proxy log levels

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, kafka-rest

I have a CLUSTER ECS with a Kafka stack installed.
My kafka-rest-proxy is generating INFO log levels. I've tried adjusting it following the documentation, but I keep getting INFO logs in my Cloudwatch.

In an article, I saw that passing the variables below should change the log level.Because of the following template: [log4j.properties.template](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest-images/blob/master/kafka-rest/include/etc/confluent/docker/log4j.properties.template)

```
ENV KAFKA_REST_LOG4J_LOGGERS="ERROR"

ENV KAFKA_REST_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL="ERROR"
```

I noticed that even with the variables declared, my file didn't change. Is this correct?

```
cat /etc/kafka-rest/log4j.properties 
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c:%L)%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.maxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.maxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.file.File=${kafka-rest.log.dir}/kafka-rest.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
```

> Cloudwatch

[image: Cloudwatch Logs]

> Dockerfile

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:7.4.0

USER root

COPY ./kafka-rest.properties /home/appuser/kafka-rest.properties
COPY ./password.properties /home/appuser/password.properties
COPY ./rest-jaas.properties /home/appuser/rest-jaas.properties

EXPOSE 80

ENV KAFKAREST_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/appuser/rest-jaas.properties"

ENV KAFKA_REST_LOG4J_LOGGERS="ERROR"

ENV KAFKA_REST_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL="ERROR"


CMD kafka-rest-start ./kafka-rest.properties
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set `CMD` on your own. This will cause the templated log4j file not to be loaded.

The `run` script is responsible for this

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest-images/blob/master/kafka-rest/Dockerfile.ubi8#L79

Best practice would also not to set `USER root`, and you should use env-vars to set `kafka-rest.properties` using its own template, not copy this file over, which may be overwritten.

Comment: I made some adjustments using SED in the LOG4j.properties file. 

RUN sed -i 's|log4j.rootLogger=INFO|log4j.rootLogger=ERROR|g' /etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties

Comment: I know it can be a bad practice. But it was the only one that worked.

Could you explain the CMD part better? I didn't understand well, thanks if you could explain =)

Comment: The confluent container has its own CMD that I linked to. If you define your own Dockerfile with that set, then it is overwritten, so no files would be templated from env-vars, for example. You don't need to `sed` when you can do something like `KAFKA_REST_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL=ERROR` instead from the ECS environment config. In other words, you should not try to copy-in your own log4j file when you can use env-vars to configure most of that file.